# Libx264 without cygwin1.dll?

Tags: dll, cygwin, mingw, msys, libx264

I have build libx264-125.dll by MinGW and Msys. However, libx254-125.dll need call cygwin1.dll and cyggcc_s-1.dll for run. 
Could anyone tell me how to build static libx264-125.dll
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you built x264 using MSYS and MinGW GCC, it does not depend on the Cygwin dll. Make sure the "gcc" used in the build process is the MinGW one, not the Cygwin executable.

Comment: How can I check gcc is the MinGw one or Cygwin one. Tks you. :D

Comment: `gcc -v`, or from within a cygwin shell where it'll be something like `i686-w64-mingw3-gcc` or `i686-pc-mingw32-gcc`. The `Target` should end in `mingw32`.

Comment: I got :
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
But how to change that ?

Comment: You install `mingw-w64-gcc` package (or whatever it's called) and call `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`.